# Log4j2 and web servlet context issues

Tags: java, jetty, log4j2, embedded-jetty

I have an interesting situation that I am trying to resolve, using Log4J 2.

The setup:

- I have a Jetty(9) embedded launcher program that deploys war files.  It is configured with its own log4j2.xml.
- I have 4 WAR files that are deployed
- The WAR files depend on some common jar files. EG., hibernate, log4j2, json, smtp etc... that are on the LOADER's classpath.
- The WAR files include a web.xml file that defines context-params to set up context-specific logging - this is so that each WAR file will write to its own log file.

It seems that in general, the logging context is working, except when a web servlet calls into the common code - that seems to be going into the log of the launcher.

I have spent a fair amount of time fiddling with this trying to make separation work properly.

I was under the impression that log4j2 logging contexts would be pulled from the current thread somehow, but it looks more like the context is being chosen from the classname.

Does log4j2 logging separation / contexts extend to covering this case?

Example web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SuperSayanServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.super.SayanServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SuperSayanServlet<servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>file:///opt/config/supersayan.log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jContextName</param-name>
    <param-value>SuperSayanServlet</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

One primary reason to share common code here is so that the database connections can be pooled better - one common pool versus 4 separate connection pools.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Seems you are making a big assumption on threading and web app servers.  There's no 1 thread per request relationship with Servlet 3.1+ anymore.  Its quite easy (and common) for a single request to be handled by multiple threads over the request/response lifetime (especially when using AsyncContext or Async I/O)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that.  But surely the servlet context would remain stable across the lifetime of the request?

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletContext remains stable across the lifetime of the deployed webapp, there's only 1 instance of a ServletContext per webapp (all servlets, filters, etc.. share it).  But knowing that doesn't help you with your logging issue.

Comment: It would seem that log4j2 is basing the logging context off of the classloader of the (passed-in) calling class, which in the case of the common code, is the classloader of the launcher. :-(